# Outlook MailItem UserProperties shared

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

How do you set a property on an Outlook.MailItem which is not subsequently shared with the recipient?

Example code:

```
Outlook.UserProperties mailUserProperties = null;
Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = null;
try
{
    mailUserProperties = mail.UserProperties;
    mailUserProperty = mailUserProperties.Add("TestUserProperty", 
       Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
    mailUserProperty.Value = "test123";
    mail.Save();
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    if (mailUserProperty != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperty);
    if (mailUserProperties != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailUserProperties);
}
```

Then if the email has been sent via Exchange, getting its `TestUserProperty` on the recipient's system still returns `test123`, so the property is shared with the recipient. This does not occur for SMTP.

So, is there a way of (a) creating a user property which is not shared with the recipient, or (b) some totally different way of attaching data to an `Outlook.MailItem` which is not shared?

Answer (score 1):

Why not delete the user property when the message is sent (Application.ItemSend)?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Cannot delete it because the property is required as a 'flag' for when the message is viewed in the Sent Items folder. Ostensibly we could unset the flag on send and then re-set it when it hits the Sent Items, but I'm not sure if this can be reliably done?

Comment: You can use Items.ItemAdd event on the Sent Items folder to restamp the message with the user property.